# 'Unpivoting' a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to 'unpivot' a table, though I'm not sure what the best way of going about it, is. Additionally, the values are separated by a ';'. I've listed a sample of what I'm looking at:

​

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | A;B;C;D | 01;02;03;04 | X;Y;D;E |
| 001 | A;B | 05;06 | S;T |
| 002 | C | 07 | S |

​
From that, I'm looking for a way to unpivot it, but also to keep the relations it's currently in. As in, the first value in Column_B, C, and D are tied together:
​
|Column_A|Column_B|Column_C|Column_D|
|:-|:-|:-|:-|
|000|A|01|X|
|000|B|02|Y|
|000|C|03|D|
|000|D|04|E|
|001|A|05|S|

And so on.

My initial thought is to use a CTE, which I've set up as:

```sql
WITH TEST AS(
SELECT DISTINCT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, VALUE AS Column_D
from [TABLE]
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Column_D, ';'))
SELECT \* FROM TEST
;
```

Though that doesn't seem to produce the correct results, especially after stacking the CTEs and string splits.

---

As an update, there were really helpful solutions below. They all ran as expected, however I had one last addition. Is it possible/reasonable to ignore a row/column if it's blank? For example, skipping over Column_C where Column_A is '001'.
|Column_A|Column_B|Column_C|Column_D|
|:-|:-|:-|:-|
|000|A;B;C;D|01;02;03;04|X;Y;D;E|
|001|A;B||S;T|
|002|C|07|S|

Comment: Why are you escapting a lot of your characters in your SQL? The real question here, however, is why are you storing delimited data in your RDBMS? You need to fix your design here

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Sounds good, sorry, I haven't posted a SQL question here before. I'll add more information.

Comment: Hopefully the purpose here isn't just one report, but fixing this **hopelessly broken** schema design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to walk through the strings.  Assuming they are all the same length (i.e. same number of semicolons):

```
with cte as (
      select a, convert(varchar(max), null) as b, convert(varchar(max), null) as c, convert(varchar(max), null) as d,
             convert(varchar(max), b + ';') as rest_b, convert(varchar(max), c + ';') as rest_c, convert(varchar(max), d + ';') as rest_d,
             0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select a,
             left(rest_b, charindex(';', rest_b) - 1),
             left(rest_c, charindex(';', rest_c) - 1),
             left(rest_d, charindex(';', rest_d) - 1),
             stuff(rest_b, 1, charindex(';', rest_b), ''),
             stuff(rest_c, 1, charindex(';', rest_c), ''),
             stuff(rest_d, 1, charindex(';', rest_d), ''),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest_b <> ''
     )
select a, b, c, d
from cte
where lev > 0
order by a, lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=faaec5175512d1e79cddabb9ca11613c) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

You can ensure filter to use rows that have the same number of semicolons by using:

```
where (length(b) - length(replace(b, ';', ''))) = (length(c) - length(replace(c, ';', ''))) and
      (length(b) - length(replace(b, ';', ''))) = (length(d) - length(replace(d, ';', '')))
```

You could also extend `c` and `d` with a bunch of semicolons so no error occurs and the resulting values are empty strings.  Extra semicolons in those columns don't matter, so you could use:

```
      select a, convert(varchar(max), null) as b, convert(varchar(max), null) as c, convert(varchar(max), null) as d,
             convert(varchar(max), b + ';') as rest_b, convert(varchar(max), c + replicate(';', length(b))) as rest_c, convert(varchar(max), d + replicate(';', length(b))) as rest_d,
             0 as lev
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! However, I am seeing a 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.' error come up on occasion. I imagine that might be due to certain rows having different length semicolons? IE it may have one extra semicolon in one column?

Comment: @fermie . . . The db<>fiddle shows that this works on the data in your question.  The answer does assume that the number of parts in each column is identical -- which is true of the data shown in the question and a very reasonable assumption given that the question does not address the possibility that this is not true.

Comment: I definitely appreciate that. I don't want to bug you unnecessarily, but in your opinion, is there an efficient way to ignore a cell if it contains more or less semicolons than another one I specify? For example, cell A2 has three ';'s, and B2 has zero ';'s. If B2 does not match A2, ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JSON based method. SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ColA varchar(3), ColB varchar(8000), ColC varchar(8000), ColD varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('000','A;B;C;D','01;02;03;04','X;Y;D;E'),
('001','A;B','05;06','S;T'),
('002','C','07','S');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS 
(
     SELECT *
         , ar1 = '["' + REPLACE(ColB, ';', '","') + '"]'
         , ar2 = '["' + REPLACE(ColC, ';', '","') + '"]'
         , ar3 = '["' + REPLACE(ColD, ';', '","') + '"]'
     FROM @tbl
 )
 SELECT ColA, ColB.[value] AS [ColB], ColC.[value] AS ColC, ColD.[value] AS ColD
 FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (ar1, N'$') AS ColB
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (ar2, N'$') AS ColC
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (ar3, N'$') AS ColD
 WHERE ColB.[key] = ColC.[key]
    AND ColB.[key] = ColD.[key];
```

**Output**

```
+------+------+------+------+
| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
+------+------+------+------+
|  000 | A    |   01 | X    |
|  000 | B    |   02 | Y    |
|  000 | C    |   03 | D    |
|  000 | D    |   04 | E    |
|  001 | A    |   05 | S    |
|  001 | B    |   06 | T    |
|  002 | C    |   07 | S    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is your design. *Hopefully* the reason you're doing this is to fix your design.

Unfortunately you can't use SQL Server's inbuilt `STRING_SPLIT` for this, as it doesn't provide an ordinal position. As such I use [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) to separate the values into rows, and then "join" then back up. This does *assume* that all the columns have the same number of delimited values.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ColA varchar(3),
                            ColB varchar(8000),
                            ColC varchar(8000),
                            ColD varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('000','A;B;C;D','01;02;03;04','X;Y;D;E'),
      ('001','A;B','05;06','S;T'),
      ('002','C','07','S');
GO

SELECT YT.ColA,
       DSLB.Item AS ColB,
       DSLC.Item AS ColC,
       DSLD.Item AS ColD
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColB,';') DSLB
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColC,';') DSLC
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColD,';') DSLD
WHERE DSLB.ItemNumber = DSLC.ItemNumber
  AND DSLC.ItemNumber = DSLD.ItemNumber;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```